# Kafka and Flink: High CPU Utilization in Kafka Brokers and Timeout Exceptions when Scaling Flink Jobs

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, cpu-usage, aws-msk

We are facing an issue with our Flink jobs that involve consuming data from Kafka. The scenario is as follows:

- We have a Flink job doing backfilling with reasonable
  performance when deployed as a single instance.
- To scale up the backfilling process, **and reduce state size of the job**, we deployed multiple instances of the Flink job (practically dividing the work), each with a parallelism of 8, creating distinct consumer groups.

However, we've encountered a significant problem: as we scale the number of job deployments, the CPU utilization of our Kafka brokers approaches 100%, leading to timeout exceptions in our Flink jobs. Despite attempting to use `request_percentage` (Kafka quotas) to throttle the consumption rate, we couldn't find a suitable value.

Here are the key aspects of the problem:

- Kafka infrastructure: AWS MSK.
- Flink infrastructure: self managed on EKS.
- Number of Deployments: 10 Flink job deployments.
- Parallelism: 8 for each deployment.
- Symptom: Kafka brokers reach nearly 100% CPU utilization, causing timeout exceptions in Flink jobs.

We have experimented with adjusting the `request_percentage` parameter, but the results have not been satisfactory. A value of `2` causes clients to become choked after a few running hours - consumer lag flattens (until then it went down continuously), meaning no messages are consumed, while requestThrottleQueueSize goes suddenly up. CPU% flattens on a high rate (60%). In other words, the jobs effectively become idle. A slightly higher value of `request_percentage` results in high CPU utilization again, leading to timeout exceptions in the Flink jobs.

We're seeking guidance on how to optimize the Kafka and Flink setup to handle such scenarios efficiently. Any insights, recommendations, or best practices would be greatly appreciated.